# Adding toolbar to UIView using XIB

Tags: ios

I am doing a simple example of tab bar based application for iPad. I have got a controller responsible to tabs management:

```
@interface MainTabBarController : UITabBarController
```

and some view controller passed to MainTabBarController as below:

```
@interface WorkspaceViewController : UIViewController
```

//

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    self.tabBarRootController = [[MainTabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainTabBarController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *workspaceController = [[[WorkspaceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WorkspaceViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.tabBarRootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:workspaceController, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarRootController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [workspaceController release];
    return YES;
}
```

The WorkspaceViewController has it own xib file. Using this XIB file I'm adding some controls to the Workspace view and everything is fine. But when I want to add (drag and drop in xib file) a toolbar it does not appear when app it run.

This is how my WorkspaceViewController XIB file looks like:

[image: XIB file]

Toolbar is connected with controller via outlet (using xib).

Could you tell what could be a reason and how to solve it? My toolbar has to be visible only when workspace view is visible and it should iteract only with workspace (workspace will be responsible for some drawing stuff and the toolbar will have options like cut, paste, copy etc.)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've done. In the xib file for WorkspaceViewController, do you see the tool bar as a subview of the main view in the objects list on the left side of the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are releasing the workspaceController again after calling `autorelease`.